# How to set a value to an enumerate property in C#

Tags: c#, enums, properties, set

I have property name and value in 2 string variables. It is easy to set when property type is for example string:

```
prop.SetValue(P, Value, null);
```

But how about an enumerate type?
Look at this example:

```
    public enum enmSex { Male, Female, Trans };
    public enum enmMaritalStatus { Married, Single, Divorced, Widowed };

    private class Person
    {
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public enmSex Sex { get; set; }
        public enmMaritalStatus MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    }

    private List<Person> People = new List<Person>();

    private void SetPersonProperty(string GivenName, string Property, string Value)
    {
        Person P = People.Where(c => c.GivenName == GivenName).First();
        PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Person).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == Property).First();
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(double))
        {
            double d;
            if (double.TryParse(Value, out d))
                prop.SetValue(P, Math.Round(d, 3), null);
            else
                MessageBox.Show("\"" + Value + "\" is not a valid floating point number.");
        }
        else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
        {
            int i;
            if (int.TryParse(Value, out i))
                prop.SetValue(P, i, null);
            else
                MessageBox.Show("\"" + Value + "\" is not a valid 32bit integer number.");
        }
        else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            prop.SetValue(P, Value, null);
        }
        else if (prop.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            prop.SetValue(P, Value, null); // Error!
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        People.Add(new Person { GivenName = "Daniel" });
        People.Add(new Person { GivenName = "Eliza" });
        People.Add(new Person { GivenName = "Angel" });
        People.Add(new Person { GivenName = "Ingrid" });

        SetPersonProperty("Daniel", "Age", "18");
        SetPersonProperty("Eliza", "Weight", "61.54442");
        SetPersonProperty("Angel", "Sex", "Female");
        SetPersonProperty("Ingrid", "MaritalStatus", "Divorced");
        SetPersonProperty("Angel", "GivenName", "Angelina");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Person item in People)
            MessageBox.Show(item.GivenName + ", " + item.Age + ", " +
                item.Weight + ", " + item.Sex + ", " + item.MaritalStatus);
    }
```

Comment: How about `MartialStatus.Divorced`? You are passing in a string instead of an enum, you could use Enum.Parse. Why are you using reflection by the way, instead of just setting the properties directly on the instances you have as in `person.Sex = Sex.Femail` ?  By the way, it's _female_, not _femail_ of course.

Comment: Apparently you need [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx) or similar, for instance `prop.SetValue(P, Enum.Parse(prop.PropertyType, Value), null);`

Comment: This is just an example I prepared for my question. My code has a very large class with several enumerate types and it is very complicated to bring it here. If you just copy and paste this code, you will encounter that error. I just do not know how to fix it. I can not also do many changes to my complicated code. Also I don't know how to use Enum.Parse. I realy want a working solution. Thanks.

Comment: Many Thanks. You saved me! This worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the string in `Value` into the desired enum type:

```
var enumValue = Enum.Parse(prop.PropertyType, Value);
```

Then pass it to `SetValue()`:

```
prop.SetValue(P, enumValue, null);
```